# Name and redirect URL of Azure AD Native App

Tags: android, ios, azure, azure-active-directory

We have created two AzureAD apps to support AzureAD authentication for our Smartsheet application: a Web app for authentication from our web app and a Native app for authentication from Android/iOS native apps.

When logging into Microsoft Azure Application (https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/applications/default.aspx) we see two apps: Smartsheet and Smartsheet Native (see attached screenshot)

[Microsoft Azure Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NBft.jpg)

Question 1: we would like to get rid of "Native" in the name of the second app. Initially we had named the app "Smartsheet Native" and removed Native from the name, but it still shows up here. Where would I edit this.

Question 2: For the Web app we have an App Url configured and when clicking the Smartsheet app we are redirected to our Smartsheet application. When clicking on the Smartsheet Native app we get an "something went wrong..." error. Is there a similar configuration we can set for the Native app or what is clicking a Native app supposed to do?

Comment: The Apps page can take a while to update, took me around 12 hours once. But anyway, you should not be accessing the native app from there since the reply URL is not a typical URL usually.

Comment: Thanks for the info!
I changed the name in December before Christmas, so the cache must be pretty long lived.
We don't intend to access the app this way, but we were concerned as we cannot prevent users from doing so and would prefer a better experience

Comment: Wow that is pretty long, I would make a support ticket about that. Yeah.. I personally think native apps should not be possible to click there.. It is not the best experience for users.

Answer (score 1):

Q1: You can push it on support, looks like some cache - I will try to ask around for it.  Also - this is client access site only for SSO to applications. your users will never use it this way anyway. Unfortunately there is no way to hide it from MyApps portal right now if user is assigned to the application (I bet you have made it available for all users).

Q2: This is Native app and it is configured to redirect user to URI on your mobile device. Then mobile device is handling response with a token on your device, that's how it is being handled to redirect response to correct application. It will not work here as you expect - I mean native apps are not meant to be used in MyApps portal as a redirection for a users. Native apps are for native apps and URI is handled on the device. your browser probably don't know how to handle the URI you have entered there (it is URI not URL - small but significant difference)

Here you will find information how to configure it when native app is using ADAL -   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication - don't know exactly how your app is being built

Comment: Thanks for the info! That makes sense.
Re Q1: I changed the name in December before Christmas so the cache must be pretty long lived.